# What Schema.org type do I use to define a service?

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

How I define a service with schema.org?

For example,
A pest control business: "Termite control" -> I think it's not a product ( http://schema.org/Product )

What should I use to define it?

Answer (score 11):

At http://schema.org/Product it reads (bold emphasis mine):

> A product is **anything** that is made available **for sale**—for example, a pair of shoes, a concert ticket, or a car. **Commodity services, like haircuts, can also be represented using this type.**

So I’d say if you sell the "Termite control" service, `Product` is fine.

**Update**: The description for `Product` changed to this:

> Any offered product or service. For example: a pair of shoes; a concert ticket; the rental of a car; a haircut; or an episode of a TV show streamed online.

So it still includes services.

---

While there is now also the type [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) ("A service provided by an organization, e.g. delivery service, print services, etc."), it misses properties to *sell* this service, i.e., you can’t reference an `Offer` and so you can’t denote a price for the service you provide.

**Update:** A `Service` can now also have the [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers) property, so it’s possible to sell/offer a `Service`. (Thanks for the notice, [@Murali KG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821216/murali-kg).)

Comment: @unor With the last update you made, it doesn't actually show it being used anywhere in a Service. Not even showing it in the examples except for Invoice. Are you sure it can be used in Service?

Comment: @adamj: As soon as a property is listed in the first table on a type’s page, you can use it. And for `Service` it (still) lists [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers). So yes, you can have a `Service` and provide an `Offer` for it via the `offers` property. -- The examples are only informational, and there are many types/properties without any example at all.

Comment: @unor Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you can use the service itemtype this way:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">

        <img  itemprop="image" src="http://my-image.jpg">
        <div itemprop="name">Service name</div>
        <span itemprop="description">Description of the service</span>
                
</div><!--end of itemscope-->
```

Unfortunately, service itemtype doesn't allow you to specify as many properties as with Product itemtype, so:

You can also use product itemtype to define a service but, some search engines might not use it if you don't follow their guideline. For instance, Google requires that:

- the main topic of the page should be a specific product
- The product should be available for purchase directly on the page
- price must be included
- It's not an adult-related products
- If the product has been reviewed by a single    reviewer, the
  reviewer’s name needs to be a valid name for a Person

See Google's [Rich snippets - Products guideline](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750#usage)

Answer (score 4):

I would advise you NOT to use the product schema for a service as there is a property specifically for [Services](http://schema.org/Service).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be fine using [ProfessionalService](http://schema.org/ProfessionalService) as `itemtype`, because to my best understanding pest control is a professional service.